# Getting check box filters to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Designer learning to code here, not too far along in my js or using jquery. Attempting to get a checkbox filter pretty much the same as this guy: http://jsfiddle.net/BCbeU/ but can't seem to get it to run like the jsfiddle on the site I'm building.

Here is my html for the checkboxes:

```
    <div class="tags">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="all"/> Show All </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="one"/> 1 Bedroom </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="two"/> 2 Bedroom </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="below"/> Below $1500 </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="above"/> Above $1500 </label>
</div>
```

Here is my html for the items I'm trying to filter:

```
<div id="shelf1-housing">
<ul class="results">
    <li class="all one">
        <a href="html/sessionone.html">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="../images/apartment2.jpg">
                    <h4>3 Bedroom Apartment</h4>
                    <h5>$1500 a month</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="all below">
        <a href="html/sessionone.html">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="../images/apartment1.jpg">
                    <h4>3 Bedroom Apartment</h4>
                    <h5>$1500 a month</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="below all">
        <a href="html/sessionone.html">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="../images/apartment2.jpg">
                    <h4>3 Bedroom Apartment</h4>
                    <h5>$1500 a month</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="all above">
        <a href="html/sessionone.html">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="../images/apartment1.jpg">
                    <h4>3 Bedroom Apartment</h4>
                    <h5>$1500 a month</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="all">
        <a href="html/sessionone.html">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="../images/apartment2.jpg">
                    <h4>3 Bedroom Apartment</h4>
                    <h5>$1500 a month</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul><!--End of Results-->
</div><!--End of Shelf1-Housing-->
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function(){
     var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
     //For each one checked
     $('input:checked').each(function(){
          $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
     });      
});
```

Thanks in advance to for the help. Still learning the basics, and they haven't got me this far yet, soon, but not yet :)

Comment: I don't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/FGetW/

Comment: I think you're using the wrong event, consider using click, not change.

Comment: @RobG - What's the difference?

Comment: In HTML 4, [change](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) was specified to fire when the control changed value and lost focus. Some browsers implemented it that way, others the way it works in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#event-input-change). So it's better to use click than change as it's more consistent.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I'll switch that and see if I can get this working. I still am getting it to work great in js fiddle but not here: http://assemblyman.co/html/filter.html I assume I am missing something super simple as far as linking jquery or the actual script, that js fiddle has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created fiddle by copying code from your website. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/LXymq/

Following changes made:
1) Added the Li back to a div with class called results. This is how you had it.
      `<div class="results"> ... All LIs ... </div>`

2) Added all your code to $(document).ready function as the code was getting executed before the dom was ready.

`$(document).ready(function() {  ... all your code inside this .... });`

4) Hardcoded the image path for beauty.

Comment: Few unknown characters in your code seems to be spoiling the script. I have copied them here. <script>
 â€‹ $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function()
 {
 var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
 //For each one checked
 $('input:checked').each(function()
 {
 $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
 });
 }); â€‹â€‹
 </script>

Comment: Thanks for the help, I plugged your code in outside of js fiddle and I can't get it to work? I assume I am missing something obvious that js fiddle adds something that I am not or doing wrong? You can see what I mean here: assemblyman.co/html/filter.html

Comment: @MatthewWilliams: Have you been able to root out those unknown chars?

Comment: No :/ I am just getting back on this now and have retyped it a few times, and tried to get rid of those spaces and still haven't gotten it to work quite right. Or am I misunderstanding how to do that?

Comment: I believe I got rid of the unknown characters per the console, but still not working...http://assemblyman.co/html/filter.html hmmm (Thank you for your help btw)

Comment: @MatthewWilliams  Created a new fiddle and all the details are in the answer above. HTH...

Answer (score 0):

This small example might be of some help.

[Check and uncheck a checkbox with jQuery](http://www.fix4query.in/check-and-uncheck-a-checkbox-with-jquery#more-98)